# Mysql aggregation across groups

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a group by multiple columns but also need an aggregation across groups

I have following table
[image]

And with following query

```
SELECT A.col1, 
       A.col2, 
       A.subgrouptotal, 
       B.grouptotal 
FROM   (SELECT col1, 
               col2, 
               Count(col1) AS SubgroupTotal 
        FROM   `mytemptbl` 
        GROUP  BY col1, 
                  col2) AS A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT col1, 
                          Count(col1) AS GroupTotal 
                   FROM   `mytemptbl` 
                   GROUP  BY col1) AS B 
               ON B.col1 = A.col1
```

I have following Result
[image]

Is there a cleaner way to do this with out doing inner join on two separate select?

Comment: Would `GROUP BY col1, col2 WITH ROLLUP` do what you need? It puts the group aggregation in its own row, not a column in every row.

Comment: ROLLUP creates a new row for GroupTotal...but i want it in a separate column

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid two Derived Tables in your query. In the base query, you can get the SubgroupTotal. You can then join this to another Sub-select (Derived Table) which gets the GroupTotal.

Try:

```
SELECT A.col1, 
       A.col2, 
       COUNT(*) AS SubgroupTotal, 
       B.GroupTotal 
FROM   mytemptbl AS A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT col1, 
                   Count(*) AS GroupTotal 
            FROM   `mytemptbl` 
            GROUP  BY col1) AS B ON B.col1 = A.col1 
GROUP BY A.col1, A.col2
```